# The result redirect to jQuery tab in Struts 2

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am using Struts 2 and jQuery plugin of Struts 2 for tabs.
For the action performed in Struts 2, I want to redirect result to same tab.
But, result is redirecting to first tab.

```xml
<action name="searchByResidentId"  class="com.carreg.controller.action.ResidentsAction"
     method="searchById">
         <result name="success">/carRegistration.jsp#tab2")</result>
</action>
```

Above code when success redirects to `tab1` instead of `tab2`.

```jsp
<sj:tabbedpanel id="localtabs" cssClass="list">
  <sj:tab id="tab1" target="tResident" label="Add Resident"/>
  <sj:tab id="tab2" target="tCar" label="Add Car"/>
</sj:tabbedpanel>
```

Comment: Use js to set current tab.

Comment: jQuery tabs are JavaScript components; you'll need to use JS to "activate" the correct tab. That said, why redirect at all? Why not just use Ajax to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

Use `href` attribute to load remote tabs.

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <sj:head />
  </head>
  <body>
    <s:url var="remoteurl1" action="searchByResidentId"/>
    <s:url var="remoteurl2" action="searchByResidentId"/>    
    <sj:tabbedpanel id="localtabs" cssClass="list" selectedTab="2" 
                  show="true" hide="'fade'" collapsible="true" sortable="true">
        <sj:tab id="tab1" href="%{remoteurl1}" label="Add Resident"/>
        <sj:tab id="tab2" href="%{remoteurl2}" label="Add Car"/>    
    </sj:tabbedpanel>
  </body>
</html>
```